# GraphQL Mutation Input Query in chain method

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-mutation

I am working in GraphQL for mutation query. I have created Argument in constructor way, I would like to convert this in chain method

```
Field<UserType>(
           "authenticate",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
               new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<UserInputType>> { Name = "user" }
             ),
```

Please help me to convert this query argument in chain method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. We can create chain method like as below :

```
.Argument<NonNullGraphType<UserInputType>, QueryArgument>(
                name: "user",
                description: "User Credentails"
            )
```